Manga about a hunter with the skill "poisoned blood"
I am searching for a full color manga I read some time ago. It's a typical hunter/ awakened manga. The mc tries to Register at the hunter association and it turns out his only skill is poisoned blood and they tell him it will be hard to find a party with his skill.

I found it. It was Hoarding in Hell by Kim, Dong-Hoon, and Corgibear:

Hyunmoo Kang is a miner scraping by in a world where those with the right talent can make millions as hunters in dungeons. One day, he inherits a mysterious hearthstone that magically transports him to a place called Hell, where he quickly dies—only to regenerate. In Hell, he hones his skills, builds talent, and hoards items that pay handsomely in his world. As Hyunmoo spends more time in Hell, he starts to wonder how this place came to be and most of all... how it connects to his own world.


Don't forget to come back to accept in two days.
